# Is it possible to make some function parameters private to the outside of an object but accessible to inside of it?

Tags: c++, recursion

I don't know if you would have to use different functions for the same task, but is it possible to do something like this in c++, but in another way?

```
void foo(int n , private Bar *bar) {}
```

I'm planning to code a recursive function into an object, but don't want *some* parameters to be accessible outside the object.

Comment: its not clear what that should mean. When you call the function (from outside) you need to pass both parameters, no? From outside there is no access to what happens inside the function anyhow

Comment: your description is quite unclear. I tried to guess what you want and wrote an answer. Please even if my guess was right, try to improve your question

Comment: nah, sorry if i was confusing , im trying my best to write in english. I solved it , I just created a different public method that calls the private one with the arguments I needed. What I meant is just , for example, that a function inside the object can add some extra arguments to the function, but those outside the object scope can't. Anyway , sorry for the confusion, and thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
struct Moo {
    static void foo(int n);
private:
    static void foo(int n,Bar* bar);
};
```

I don't like classes with only static methods (for reasons beyond the scope of this question), but thats the most simple to get what you ask for. `foo(int)` is public, the other overload is private (and can only be called from `foo(int)`).

Alternatively, instead of the `Bar` parameter, make `foo` a member of `Bar` and use private members instead of the parameter:

```
struct Bar {
    void foo(int n);
private:
    // state, ie anything that you would have passed as argument to foo
};
```

Comment: Thanks dude , I'm kind of new to c++, and this helped me quite a lot.